# Why is Ubuntu suddenly crippling my network?

Tags: wireless, 14.04, networking, xubuntu, 64-bit

I'm running Xubuntu 14.04 64-bit. I have recently started noticing randomly that my wireless adaptor suddenly becomes a jamming device for the network I'm connected to!

I see 0Kbit/s in my network meter incoming, but 200Kbit/s going out on the wlan0 interface.

Suddenly, everyone on the network I'm connected to begins having connectivity issues. This only happens when my laptop is on, connected via wifi, and on Ubuntu. I have been able to reproduce the issue on a live session as well.

Here is some infos:

```
westj@TwilightSparkle:~$ iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"GOAT SIMULATOR 2013"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.447 GHz  Access Point: 14:D6:4D:32:DB:98   
          Bit Rate=65 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=38/70  Signal level=-72 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:664  Invalid misc:794   Missed beacon:0

westj@TwilightSparkle:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for westj: 
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: 68:94:23:cd:c3:ef
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=3.16.1-031601-generic firmware=0.37 ip=192.168.1.100 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:16 memory:c3510000-c351ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 05
       serial: 84:34:97:79:c8:1a
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:42 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c3404000-c3404fff memory:c3400000-c3403fff
```

I would be very grateful for any help you can give me!
[EDIT] Someone told me this would help too: http://pastebin.com/vh1rVuxf

Comment: What kind of WIFI router, is it CISCO and/or linksys?

Comment: Any router, CISCO, D-Link, Linksys, OpenWRT, DD-WRT, ClearOS running on a netbook, doesn't matter. It will screw over any network and the users on it.

Comment: The reason I ask is because I recently experienced issues on my friend's cisco linksys router last week and the network signal kept cutting out. Then, yesterday, I visited a relative with another cisco router and had the same problem. Both running cisco firmware. Now wondering if the issue is related to yours. I have no problems at home but my router firmware is custom built. Also, I use a different wireless card and not the same drivers.

Comment: Run the command `nm-tool` in an open terminal. The subsequent output will show your access point and all other networks within range. If your network is using the same frequency as *any* other network listed. Switch your router to a different channel.

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible that Ubuntu doesn't have the required tools (configurations, drivers, ect...) to properly interface with your wireless adapter. I have seen cases where Ubuntu would severely decrease signal strength because of driver issues, I assume it could work the other way around.

Comment: It is specific to this network adaptor, but how would I go about fixing this? I've tried several kernels.

Comment: @WestJ There were some issues with your driver a while back but from what I understand, the issue has been fixed since 13.10.